# Xcode 3.2.6 to Xcode 4.2

Tags: xcode, layout, toolbar

Does xcode 4.2 have the following "toolbar" or "view" or "window" with the build, stop, clean options at the top?  If so, what is it called and how do I enable it?

*Picture is of Xcode 3.2.6

[image: 3.2.6]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest I could find was the toolbar.  It can be found here:

[image]